Change option colors in AcroForm Reportlab
class InteractiveDropdown(Flowable):
    def __init__(self, text='Choose Here'):
        Flowable.__init__(self)
        self.text = text
  

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.saveState()
        form = self.canv.acroForm
        options = ['Not Detected', 'Moderate', 'Detected']
        value = 'Not Detected'
        
        form.choice(options=options,
                    value=value,
                    relative=True,
                    height=12,
                    fontName = 'Times-Bold',
                    borderWidth=0,
                    fillColor=colors.white,
                    textColor=colors.black,
                    
                    )
        
        self.canv.restoreState()

I need to change the color of my options of Not Detected to be black and Detected to be red

Is it possible to feed different colors for options?

